# Reference another function parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there any way to mirror class method parameters visible in parent class?

Example to clarify:

```js
export abstract class AbstractDoIt {
  protected abstract handle(
    ...params: unknown[]
  ): Promise<void> | void;

  /* "final", not overloaded method */
  public doIt(
    ...handleParams: Parameters<this['handle']> // mirror here
  ): void {
    // pre actions ...
    this.handle(...handleParams);
    // post actions ...
  }
}

class HelloDoIt extends AbstractDoIt {
  protected async handle(a: string, b: number, c: boolean) {
     // here the handle logic
     log('hello')
  }
}
```

In another point, using classes who inherits `AbstractDoIt`

I want to:

```js
...

const test = new HelloDoIt();
test.doIt(); // error, the parameters doesn't match with handle(...) defined parameters in HelloDoIt
test.doit("a", 1, null); // error
test.doit("a", 1, true); // magic

...
```

Comment: Here "class method parameters visible in parent class", you mean types of parameters or its values?

Comment: Hi @ShSvyatoslav!
I mean the parameter's type, i expect that on HelloDoIt, the call for .doIt() (defined in parent class) mirror handle() (in child class) params, to have a typecheck when calling doIt to execute handler and post actions

Comment: Compiler do static type checking, it could do some predictions, but not in this case. In runtime all you can do is implement type checking manually with "typeof" etc.

To simplify handler writing, maybe you can try "reflect.metadata" and do some code generation (you should write some code that do check values based on parameter types), but no common handler you can write :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. Abstract class must be independent of any derived class.

The best you could do is to use the `unknown` type.

Comment: Yes!, i'm finding a way to, after extended, infer the parents handle params definition when calling from parent instance